# ODE in complex domain

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If $f(z)=f'(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, I know that the general solution is $Ce^{x}$ if $z=x\in\mathbb{R}$. Can we apply this general solution on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: in a word, yes, we can

Comment: "The proof of the pudding is in the eating." since exp(z) is given by exactly the same power series for complex z as it is for real z, put f(z) =C exp(z) and check whether or not your desired equation is true by differentiating term-by-term.